# Is there a way to change a Word document's filename and email subject using combobox data (VBA)?

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, filenames

I'm trying to set up a form so that when a subject - in the example I have, it's animals - is selected from a ComboBox, it changes both the file name and also the subject line of the email. Currently, it just sends an email when you click the submit button, but I need to differentiate between files depending on which subject is selected. I've tried searching for an answer, but I've so far not come across anything related.

The ComboBox has four entries in it. Tiger, Monkey, Elephant, Giraffe.

The ComboBox is named "Animals" and it's tag is "ComboBox1"

Unfortunately, for whatever reason, I am unable to upload a picture, but it is a "Combo Box Content Control" if that helps. Apologies, I have limited knowledge of this stuff, it's mostly been trial and error to get me to this point and borrowing other pieces of code.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
Dim objInspector As Object
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objRange As Range
Dim sDocname As String




ActiveDocument.Save
sDocname = ActiveDocument.FullName

If Len(ActiveDocument.Path) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Document is not saved!"
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Outlook is not running."

    GoTo lbl_Exit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.createitem(0)
With objOutlookMsg
    .To = "email@emailaddress.com"
    .Cc = ""
    .Subject = "Favourite Animal is "
    .attachments.Add sDocname
    Set objInspector = .GetInspector
    Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
    Set objRange = objDoc.Range(0, 0)
    .Display
    objRange.Text = "My favourite animal is the "


    .Send
End With
lbl_Exit:
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objRange = Nothing
Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objInspector = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks, Cindy. I couldn't add a screenshot, unfortunately, but I have put in the information that you have asked for. If there's anything else you need clarification on, please ask.

Comment: Thank you for adding the fact that this is a content control. The original wording of the question led us to think a VBA UserForm might be meant. What happened when you tried to upload a picture? For people who are new, only the link is allowed, but others with more site reputation will edit it in for you...

Comment: Sorry, @CindyMeister, I must've missed this comment. Unfortunately, as this is a work computer, a lot of sites are locked, so I can't really upload the image without being able to do it through this site. I'm just lucky that I can get on here (for now!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
Dim objInspector As Object
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objRange As Range
Dim sDocname As String

'new declarations.
Dim cmb As ContentControl
Dim sSelText As String

'get a reference of the combobox.
    Set cmb = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Combobox1")(1)
'get the selected item in a variable.
    sSelText = cmb.Range.Text
    Set cmb = Nothing
'enforce making a selection.
    If sSelText = "DEFAULT_TXT" Then 'write here the default text of your combobox.
        MsgBox "Please select subject from the dropdown menu.", vbCritical, "No selection!"
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Save
        sDocname = ActiveDocument.FullName
        If Len(ActiveDocument.Path) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Document is not saved!", vbCritical, "Error!"
            GoTo lbl_Exit
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If Err <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not running."
            GoTo lbl_Exit
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.createitem(0)
        With objOutlookMsg 'use the selected item as you wish.
            .To = "email@emailaddress.com"
            .Cc = ""
            .Subject = "Favourite Animal is " & sSelText
            .attachments.Add sDocname & "_" & sSelText
            Set objInspector = .GetInspector
            Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
            Set objRange = objDoc.Range(0, 0)
            .Display
            objRange.Text = "My favourite animal is the " & sSelText
            .Send
        End With
    End If
lbl_Exit:
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objRange = Nothing
Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objInspector = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @Dimitris, thanks for the response. I have plugged it in and I get an error saying, "Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct". 

It works fine when I delete,`& "_" & sSelText` but obviously that stops the email subject from changing.

Comment: Hi @Tristan. Tell me please which line throws the error?

Comment: Sorry, @Dimitris, it's this one:

`.attachments.Add sDocname & "_" & sSelText`

Comment: Hmm that should be expexted. It's my mistake.  First you have to create this file and then attach it. There are two options. Either rename the current document and attach it, or "save as" this document to leave the current document unchanged.

Comment: Oh, okay. I figured I had done something wrong! A Save As function would work fine. I'll have a crack at that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I managed to get it all working the way it should be! Cheers!